# Why the system doesn't recognize python3.7 as the python3 installed? (for distutils)

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, python3

The ubuntu version is 18.04. The pc is in a environment which can't access internet, but can acess to a limited storage with apt and pip packages. I am trying to install distutils_3.7 on it (I use python3.7 mostly and it takes a lot of effort to install various python libs without internet so not considering upgrading yet).

At first I tried to install with:

```
apt install python3-distutils
```

, then it shows the message:

```
python3-distutils is already the newest version(3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)
```

So i realized that that is a python3.8 installed on the system (but why ubuntu1~20.04? ). Nevertheless I download a "python3-distutils_3.7.3-1_all.deb" and

```
dpkg -i python3-distutils_3.7.3-1_all.deb
```

then it shows the message:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distutils:
python3-distutils depends on python3 (<< 3.8); however:
 Version of python3 on system is 3.8.2-0ubuntu2.
```

So I tried to remove python3.8 via

```
apt remove python3.8
```

then in the hope that it would  install distutils for my python3.7 now, I tried:

```
apt install python3-distutils
```

sadly it shows the message, implying it's going to install both distutils for 3.8 along with python3.8:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3 python3-lib2to3 python3.8
```

So I selected no, and then again i tried to force it to install python3-distutils_3.7 by:

```
dpkg -i python3-distutils_3.7.3-1_all.deb
```

Then it shows the message:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-distutils:
python3-distutils depends on python3 (>= 3.7.1-1~); however:
  Package python3 is not installed.
python3-distutils depends on python3 (<< 3.8); however:
  Package python3 is not installed.
```

But if i type:`python3 -V` or `python -V`

It both shows:

```
Python 3.7.5
```

So it seems the python3.7 I have been using is recognized as python3 somehow but not when I tried to install distutils? Is there a method for me to install distutils for my python3.7 in this situation? I don't care if there will be a python3.8 or other version on my system though.